# Excel Import Not Recognizing Tables

Tags: excel, import

I'm trying to import web data to excel--specifically 10 day weather forecasts, and I'm trying to do it in the simplest way possible. I've read a few excel tutorials that say to just click "get external data" "from web" and then when the website comes up there should be an arrow next to any tables, etc, that I can import to excel. My problem is that there are never any arrows. It gives me the option to import the whole page, but when I do that it only picks up a few keywords and none of the temperature data that I need.

Ideally, I want to be able to have it refresh every day to get the new 10-day forecast, but to keep the data from the previous day as well, but this is a little beyond where I am right now, so I guess what I'm most concerned about is why there are no importable tables on the websites. Most websites have their 10-day forecast organized pretty much in a table, so I assumed (incorrectly) that excel would pick that out as something for import.

I have no idea if this is relevant, but sometimes after I've opened the page I want in the excel web query window, I get a pop up saying there's a script error--sometimes it gives an error message, sometimes not, depending on the page--and I've tried choosing yes and no and it doesn't seem to change anything either way. Sometimes it only comes up once, and sometimes no matter which I choose I keep getting the same pop up over and over. If it eventually does go away, no matter what I choose there still aren't arrows to import the tables. Anyway, I don't know if this is related at all to my other problems.

My main question is: is there any way to import these tables even though excel isn't suggesting them to be imported? Or, will I have to resort to some kind of web scraping/use beautifulsoup or something? I'm using excel 2013, if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern web development often doesn't use the `<table>` tag for layout control, yet the wizard you want to use most likely relies on just that tag.. There is an excellent chance that there is no such tag in the website you wish to scrape. To verify this, you can open the website in your favorite browser and view the HTML source code of the site. Look for `<table>`.

> is there any way to import these tables even though excel isn't suggesting them to be imported?

Yes, but it requires some programming. If you are comfortable with (or willing to learn) C# (or any .NET based language), have a look at [HTML Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). It is an excellent and free library intended for just this kind of task.

**Note**

Screen scraping is always a tricky matter because your code relies on the structure of the user interface, which the website developers might change from time to time. Be aware of this possibility.

Comment: Thanks so much--that makes perfect sense. I'm going to go with some kind of programming solution. Can you think of any other way to consistently access the data that isn't screen scraping? Eventually, this needs to become automated--I know I could just go online every day and collect the data myself but the point of this project is to make it so I don't have to do that. I know that web scraping is nonideal because of the possibility of the website changing--do you know of any other solution that would work around this, or should I just hope things don't change too much?

Comment: Look for a provider of the data you need that offers an API. Here's one I found by googling http://openweathermap.org/api